# Como mostrar dados do banco em Textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

Olá! Meu cenário é o seguinte:

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web em C# ASP.NET, e estou tendo algumas dificuldades para trazer os dados do banco (via LINQ to SQL) para os controles da página.

Abaixo um dos controles do meu arquivo `.aspx` onde desejo trazer uma determinada informação do banco

```
 <asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtCodigo" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    CssClass="form-control"
    MaxLength="4"
    Enabled="false"
    runat="server">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

E abaixo o meu `.aspx.cs`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            int idCliente;
            TB_CLIENTE_CLI cliente = new TB_CLIENTE_CLI();
            if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out idCliente))
            {
                ClienteBusiness.ListarCliente(idCliente);

                txtCodigo.Text = cliente.ID_CLIENTE_CLI.ToString();
                txtRazaoSocial.Text = cliente.TXT_RAZAOSOCIAL_CLI;
                txtNomeFantasia.Text = cliente.TXT_NOMEFANTASIA_CLI;
                txtCNPJ.Text = cliente.TXT_CNPJ_CLI;
                txtCEP.Text = cliente.TXT_CEP_CLI;
                txtLogradouro.Text = cliente.TXT_LOGRADOURO_CLI;
            }

}
```

Minha aplicação está dividida em camadas. O método `ClienteBusiness.ListarCliente(idCliente)` chama outro método que, por sua vez, faz a consulta ao banco, conforme mostra o código abaixo:

```
public static List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> ListarCliente(int idCliente)
    {
        List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> cliente = null;
        using (PlanoTesteDataContext context = new PlanoTesteDataContext())
        {
            cliente = (from clientes in context.TB_CLIENTE_CLIs
                       where clientes.ID_CLIENTE_CLI == idCliente
                       select clientes).ToList();
        }
        return cliente;
    }
```

Comment: Está passando por qual dificuldade especificamente? O método está retornando alguma exceção em algum ponto?

Comment: Olá Pedro! Os dados simplesmente não são exibidos. Não recebo nenhuma exception ou erro.

Comment: "Debugando" o código você verificou se está entrando no if e valores estão sendo exibidos? Se sim, você pode ir "debugando" colocando na janela Watch do Visual Studio para ver se em algum momento do fluxo da requisição esse valor é apagado.

Comment: Pedro, haviam alguns erros nos meus métodos, que o Eduardo listou e assim consegui resolver o problema. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no seu códdigo:

1. No `Page_Load` o comando `ClienteBusiness.ListarCliente(idCliente);` não popula o objeto `cliente`, já que nada recebe o retorno do métood `listarCliente(...)`.
2. O método `public static List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> ListarCliente(int idCliente)` retorna uma lista ao passo que deveria retornar apenas um objeto cliente, para que seu código no `Page_Load`faça sentido.

A linha `ClienteBusiness.ListarCliente(idCliente);` no método `Page_Load` deveria ser: `cliente = ClienteBusiness.ListarCliente(idCliente);`.

O método `public static List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> ListarCliente(int idCliente)` deveria ser implementado da seguinte maneira:

```
public static List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> ListarCliente(int idCliente)
{
    List<TB_CLIENTE_CLI> cliente = null;
    using (PlanoTesteDataContext context = new PlanoTesteDataContext())
    {
        cliente = (from clientes in context.TB_CLIENTE_CLIs
                   where clientes.ID_CLIENTE_CLI == idCliente
                   select clientes).ToList();
    }
    return cliente.First();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções, Eduardo! Consegui resolver o problema de acordo com as suas recomendações.